# Deserialization in Custom Collection Class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, stream

I've got a custom collection which adds functionality to the 'ArrayList' class.

Here's some code from the class:

```
    [Serializable]
    class Coll : ArrayList
    {

       public void Save(string path)
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                formatter.Serialize(fsOut, this);
                fsOut.Dispose();
            }
    }
```

I'm now trying to deserialize a file, and fill the collection with the contents of the file. Basically the opposite of my `Save(string path)` method.

This is what I've got so far:

```
public void Read(string path)
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                formatter.Deserialize(fsIn);
                fsIn.Dispose();
            }
```

How should I go about populating the collection with the contents which has been deserialized?

Comment: Why don't you use the return vaule of `Deserialize`?

Comment: That's the part I'm stuck on. How should I populate the array from that output?

Comment: Take the (de)serialization bit out of the collection, [a collection should be for storing things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). Then just deserialize the entire collection as a whole (though you could use an extension method to achieve the same kind of syntax)

Comment: you can do something like Coll other = formatter.Deserialize(fsIn) as Coll; foreach (var item in other){ this.Add(item); } but it comes with a big overhead and is unsolid per definition. Better declare your serialization logic outside of your collection

Comment: Or make the Read method static returning the result from formatter.Deserialize(fsIn) cast as an Coll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` doesn't support serialising **into** an existing object. You could deserialize it into a **new** list - just make it a `static` method and return the value.

Other thoughts:

- don't use `ArrayList` unless you are in .net 1.1: `List<T>` would be preferable
- no need to subclass; an extension method would suffice
- I don't recommend `BinaryFormatter` for this... Or anything else really

Comment: Technically, you could serialize into an existing object using serialization surrogate. But doing that is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The method [BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz.aspx) creates a new object, initializes it with the data from the stream and returns it. Therefore, you should use the return value and use it as the new `ArrayList` object. The `Read` method thus goes into a static method, or -- as *diggingforfire* suggested -- into another class.